# Why does INSERT INTO statement create two records instead of one?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot figure out why my very simple MySQL statement inserts two records instead of just one. I have a very simple table with three columns: id auto increment integer, timestamp, and varchar. When I execute MySQL query from PHP script two records are inserted into table instead of one.

Table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE `footable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `curDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `col1` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `footable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `footable`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
COMMIT;
```

and PHP script is:

```
<?php
require("../db/db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO footable(col1) VALUES ('blabla')");
$stmt->execute();
```

db.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database", 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When MySQL statement is executed from phpMyAdmin result is as expected.

Here is what I got from Network

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check, if your PHP is executing 2 times (postback / reload ?)...

Comment: maybe in db.php, you are executing the same script. check it again and also try to echo some text to check how many times your script is executed!

Comment: Nothing forbids to insert the rows with the same values (except `id`) into the table. No chance to define does the value is legal, or it is errorneous duplicate.

Comment: I updated question with db.php. So, this is the whole php sript.

Comment: Temporarily alter the datatype for `curDate` to `timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3)`, and show the difference between the times in duplicated rows.

Comment: Does the value of `col1` must be unique (at all, per day, per hour...) by its meaning?

Comment: `So, this is the whole php sript.`...sure. but the thing you need to check is whether that script is being run twice when you only expected it to run once. How are you triggering the scrip from a web form? Or command line? Or Cron job?

Comment: @ADyson Script is triggered through browser address bar

Comment: @Akina; No, col1 doesn't need to be unique. As a matter of fact, I don't need this column at all, but otherwise MySQL doesn't accept table with just id and timestamp.

Comment: Then check you aren't pressing Enter twice, or calling it again through AJAX, or anything like that. Your webserver logs (e.g. Apache or IIS logs) will be able to tell you if multiple HTTP requests to that script are being made.

Comment: `MySQL doesn't accept table with just id and timestamp`...that's not true. Proof: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07f21331117dad2e1d9490d5ce658514

Comment: *MySQL doesn't accept table with just id and timestamp.* Easily. `INSERT INTO footable (id, curDate) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)`. Or simply `INSERT INTO footable (id) VALUES (NULL);`

Comment: Thank you @ADyson. But, what;s wrong is then with syntax ```INSERT INTO `footable`;``` [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56ba0a20b46c0ea85613bdebda177b66)

Comment: `INSERT INTO \`footable\`` doesn't work because you can't leave the fields and values you want to insert unspecified. What would you expect the code to do in that scenario? Do you expect it to insert a line with all fields NULL? What would be the point of that? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html tells you how to write an INSERT statement.

Comment: @ADyson i didn't want to insert NULLs. I wanted current timestamps.

Comment: I updated my question and included what I got from traffic monitoring. Can someone tell me how to solve this? It seems like a trivial thing, but I cannot figure out why this is happening. I even tried to insert random into col1, but the same thing happens

Comment: That's the local monitoring in your web page. The webserver logs would be a better place to look.

Comment: @ADyson I don't have webserver. But, what would be the difference? Doesn't local host emulate it?

Comment: `I don't have webserver`...of course you do. Otherwise how are you running the PHP code? Do you use Apache maybe? Or IIS? Or nginx? Or something else? You can run all these webservers on localhost just the same as you can on another machine designated as a server.

Comment: `i don't know what postback / reload is`...you seem to know almost nothing about how web applications work in general, then. Maybe stop trying to run before you can walk, and educate yourself on the basics of web-based applications, before trying to write applications which rely on those concepts.

Comment: @ADyson ```you seem to know almost nothing about how web applications work in general```. I acknowledge that I do not know much about that. But, do you know how to fix this? I would be very grateful if you gave me a useful tip.

Comment: `Can you tell me where to locate those logs` ...that depends on which webserver product you use in your localhost, what operating system you use, and whether you've changed any of the default configs. Documentation for the product should tell you this anyway.

Comment: @TheMixy OP already stated `Script is triggered through browser address bar ` in an earlier comment.